# What does it mean to 'distil' a configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2

I read on the CPanel documentation that

> "...The build process begins by
>   distilling and recording Apache’s
>   current configuration...."

and

> The new configuration is distilled in
>   much the same way as before

see: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/EA3Overview

What does it mean to distil a configuration file?

- Is that a technical term?
- Is it CPanel-specific terminology?
- or just that it boils off the water to increase the alcohol content of the Apache config file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a CPanel thing. The idea is that the "distiller" reads a configuration file and extracts the "essence" of what it means into a separate, cpanel-specific format which is presumably easier for the cpanel code to work with.

Comment: thanks - do you know where this process is described/defined in the docs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you linked to them. :)

Comment: those docs refer to distillation but I was hoping for a bit more detail on how the distillation process itself is implemented.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no good docs for the details. I'd ask on the cpanel forums (or search there -- a cursory search turned up not much).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary.com gives this as one of the definitions:  "to extract the essential elements of; refine; abstract: She managed to distill her ideas into one succinct article. "

Sounds like what CPanel has done is make a process out of pulling only the elements that are pertinent to a separate file.

This concludes the English language lesson for today.

Comment: +1 for comedic value, -1 someone already said the same thing.